# How to save position on temporary table which is the composite of two other tables?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am constructing the moderation engine in which moderator should be able to save position of the last seen message assuming the total messages entities should from 100k to millions of records.

The message database structure is consist of two tables `question` and `reply` and represented as following:

`question` table:

```
+-------------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
| Field                   | Type             | Null | Key | Default             | Extra          |
+-------------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
| entity_id               | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL                | auto_increment |
| text                    | mediumtext       | NO   |     | NULL                |                |
| customer_id             | int(10) unsigned | YES  | MUL | NULL                |                |
+-------------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
```

and `reply` table, `parent_id` is `FK` to `question.entity_id` :

```
+-------------+------------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
| Field       | Type             | Null | Key | Default           | Extra          |
+-------------+------------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
| entity_id   | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL              | auto_increment |
| text        | mediumtext       | NO   |     | NULL              |                |
| customer_id | int(10) unsigned | YES  | MUL | NULL              |                |
| parent_id   | int(10) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL              |                |
+-------------+------------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
```

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a06077

Because this is two separate tables with parent-child relationship the only thought that i have is to create a temporary composite table `messages` like this:

> question1->reply1.1->reply1.2->reply1.3->question2->reply2.1->reply2.2... etc

and make a slice of it, from the last saved position viewed by moderator, assuming the last saved position is id of last viewed message in this temporary table.

So, the questions are:

1. How to properly craft an sql to insert question-replies in temporary table if it structure is as following:

   ```
   CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp (
           id INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
           text  varchar(16),
           is_question boolean
       );
   ```
2. How to properly construct this temporary table assuming messages and replies will constantly growing?
3. Will it affect performance on large entries quantity (we are using `MySQL`)?
4. Is there a better way to implement such functionality?

I have not much experience in large database constructing and would love to get some advice or critics or any ideas regarding this task from more experienced engineers.

Comment: create a sqlfiddle to increase people's interest.

Comment: thanks, i have added sqlfiddle, maybe in summary i did not asked question clearly ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my recommendation if someone were to say spend 20 minutes and show it.

```
create database QRMod123xyz; -- create a new safe sandbox away from your tables
use QRMod123xyz; -- use this db

drop table if exists reply; -- reverse order on drop (at least for the FK ones at the moment)
drop table if exists question; -- this comes second
drop table if exists moderator_qr_seen_history;

create table question 
(   question_id int auto_increment key primary key, 
    theText mediumtext, -- don't use reserved or keywords for column names
    customer_id int  
    -- dont forget useful indexes and FK to customer table 
)engine=INNODB; 

create table reply 
(   reply_id int auto_increment key, 
    theText mediumtext, 
    question_id int not null, 
    sequence_id int not null, -- sequence of read (1..n) per question_id. See notes at bottom.
    customer_id int not null, -- could be more than 1 customer for a given question id in theory 
    theDT datetime not null, 
    unique key (question_id,sequence_id), 
    constraint fk_question foreign key (`question_id`) references question(`question_id`) 
    -- dont forget useful indexes and FK to customer table 
)engine=INNODB;

create table moderator_qr_seen_history 
(   -- modify this to your heart's content depending on your intentions
    id int auto_increment primary key,
    question_id int not null,
    reply_id int not null,
    moderator_id int not null,
    theText mediumtext, 
    customer_id int not null,
    theDT datetime not null,    -- when seen (note, a moderator can have several rows for a "Q R" combo
    key(question_id,moderator_id)   -- NOTE Aboy this will narrow things down (big time filter)
   -- dont forget useful indexes and all FK's
)engine=INNODB;

... do other stuff (save your scripts !)


drop database QRMod123xyz; -- cleanup when complete
```

NOTE A (above reference): that key will narrow things down with a big time filter. It won't be a covering index, though. It is just an idea. Only you will know after adequate testing what *your* index strategy should be.

See also [Keywords and Reserved Words](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html). Don't use them in column names.

I would not use temporary tables.

I would acquire the `sequence_id` with a wrapped transaction including a [FOR UPDATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-locking.html) lock on the `question` table as a gateway to getting that question's next available sequence (via `ifnull(max(sequence_id),0)`. Inserting the reply with that next available number that is incremented. Then a `COMMIT`.

A quick visual on the ifnull max is below in a trivial case. But you would use it against the `reply` table with the appropriate `where` clause. Note, this supports normalization and with the transaction, safety.

```
create table a (i int not null,sequence_id int not null);
insert a(i,sequence_id) values (1,1),(1,2);
select ifnull(max(sequence_id),0) as prevMax from a where i=1;
-- answer is 2
select ifnull(max(sequence_id),0) as prevMax from a where i=7;
-- answer is 0
```

That is the best I have for you in 20 minutes.

Comment: thanks for detailed explanation !  did i correctly understood that `sequence_id` in `reply` table would increment for every `question` entity ? so `replies` for first question would be 1,2,3,4,5 and for second question 6,7,8,9 ?

Comment: not in my mind. each question has its own sequence (starting over at 1). You can make whatever out of it as you want. Some would just use the ascending order of `theDate` as a rank (incrementer) but I would be explicit about it